# Scrollview in react native not scrolling

Tags: react-native

Hello guys hope u doing good ! I wanna know why `Scrollview` isn't working over here? I imported it from react-native so it should be working ? I have seen some solution that say you have to add flex style to it but I did it and the `Stories` component disappeared from the app!

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image,Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import  USERS from '../../data/storiesDummy';

const Stories=()=>{
    return(
        
       <View style={{marginBottom:13 }}>
           <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}  > 
           {USERS.map((story,index)=>(
               <View key={index} style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                 <Image source={{uri: story.image}}
                 style={styles.stories}/>
                 <Text style={{color:'white'}}>{
                     story.user.length > 10 ? story.user.slice(0,10).toLowerCase()+'...'
                    : story.user.toLowerCase() }    
                </Text>
               </View>
           ))}
           </ScrollView>

         
       </View>
    );
}
const styles =StyleSheet.create({
  stories:{
      width:70,
      height:70,
      borderRadius:50,
      marginLeft:6,
      borderWidth:3,
      borderColor:'#ff8501',
  }
})

export default Stories;
```

Answer (score 0):

For vertical scroll remove horizontal and showsHorizontalScrollIndicator from ScrollView

Link to live example - https://snack.expo.dev/ngXxvwgx7

Live horisontal example - https://snack.expo.dev/Tc0ScUOR1

Comment: but bro i want horizontal scroll not vertical its like instagram stories it scrolls horizontally

Comment: @ZakiKendil I updated my answer